# I can no longer build and deploy with Jenkins on OpenShift

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, openshift

I use Tomcat 7 (Jboss EWS 2.0) and a Jenkins client on OpenShift. Everything worked fine for about 3 months, but since a few days I can no longer build and deploy with Jenkins. When I start the job, jenkins displays the message: *"All nodes of label 'jbossews-build' are offline*" and no job is started. I use only one gear for Tomcat and one for Jenkins, there should be one gear for a bldr app.

Had somebody the same problem on OpenShift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenShift has implemented a scalable design for it's hosted Jenkins service that spins up new Jenkins worker environments in order to processes each build.

This design requires you to have an extra OpenShift gear instance available when a given build task is run.  If your account has sufficient capacity, then you should be able to run several builds in parallel.

If you want to use Jenkins on OpenShift's Free plan, then I'd try keeping one spare gear available at all times to make sure that Jenkins is able to keep working.

For users who have upgraded to one of OpenShift's paid plans: OpenShift does not charge hourly fees for the additional resources that are used while running your Jenkins workers / build tasks. (no hourly fees for running a build, since it takes less than an hour)

Comment: I have one gear available to process builds. First I had the problem that this gear was not destroyed after a build, then I deleted the application manually. Now I have the problem to start a new build process.

Comment: I'd probably try destroying and re-creating the Jenkins master to see if that clears the issue.

Comment: Today I coud start a build but I got alwas an exeption after a few minuts.                                                                          FATAL: hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel
hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel
 at hudson.remoting.Request.call(Request.java:174)
 at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:672)

Comment: I destroyed and re-created the Jenkins application and it works as desired. Thanks!